# Owncloud icon is misplaced

Tags: icons, owncloud-client

The owncloud icon is at the left end of the top bar. It is annoying since it overlaps the "X" to exit from whatever application at full screen.

The command

```
unity --reset-icons
```

does not solve it.

Comment: As an indication on how to solve; would stop and start ownlcloud place the icon in the right position.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. AFAIK, it's caused by a Qt update for 16.04 that doesn't work for 14.04.  In the bug report, a user called awnz proposed a workaround: downgrading to 2.0.2 version (https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/4828#issuecomment-219307594). It works for me.

To downgrade the owncloud client, you have to compile the older version from the source. Here are some instructions to do so. Please, let me know if this workaround works for you too.

1. Remove the current client:

`sudo apt-get remove owncloud-client`

2. Install some dependences:

`sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev doxygen cmake`

`sudo apt-get build-dep owncloud-client`

3. Download source of 2.0.2 version:

`wget https://github.com/owncloud/client/archive/2.0.2.zip`

4. Extract the zip file:

`mkdir ~/.client-2.0.2`

`unzip 2.0.2.zip -d ~/.client-2.0.2`

`cd ~/.client-2.0.2`

5. Configure the client build:

`cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ../.client-2.0.2`

6. Install:

`make`

`sudo make install`

7. Finally, you have to remove the owncloud repository from your sources to prevent further updates.

As the owncloud developers will fix the bug soon, this should be just a temporary solution. When the fix is released, you have to uninstall the old version and install the new one using the official repo.

Uninstalling:

`cd ~/.client-2.0.2`

`sudo make uninstall`

Comment: The official repository was updated today and the problem is fixed. So, the workaround is unnecesary.